# How would I connect these up...?

Tags: parent, lattice

I'm a bit confused as to how I'd connect these up. Basically, I parented the eyes to the H.eye, so where the targets are moved, the eyes follow. However, if the head is rotated too far, the eyes will bulge out due to their lattices staying in place. I've tried mixing and matching by parenting the lattice to the head, the eye, the target etc. in order to get both to follow the head and the eye target naturally.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you're in pose mode with your armature. Then, still in Pose mode:

- Select both your eye's lattice objects (it will turn back on object mode, no worries)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the head's bone (it should switch automatically to pose mode, otherwise do it manually)
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → Set parent to Bone

This way your lattices are following the head's bone.

The only remaining advice I would give you is to use a constraint Child Of on your `C_look_target` bone, to make it parented to the head's bone.
That way, the eyes, and their target will follow the head, as well as the lattices, which is usually more practical to use when posing.
When you will need to move the head while the eyes target stay still, simply animate the Child Of influence parameter from 1 to 0, and vice versa when you need the opposite behavior.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. That's done the trick nicely. :D